# how to accept payment with bitcoin in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, bitcoin, coinpayments-api

I am building an e-commerce website with bitcoin with ionic framework, now my problem is that I want my users to be able to pay with bitcoin, I have searched online for bitcoin payment API that support ionic or angular, but found none, I tried using Coinbase, and others but it doesn't have any API that support angular or ionic.

```html
     <form action="https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_pay_simple">
        <input type="hidden" name="reset" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="606a89bb575311badf510a4a8b79a45e">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="amountf" value="10.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_desc" value="Item Description">
        <input type="hidden" name="want_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="http://www.yoursite.com/success">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.coinpayments.net/images/pub/buynow-med.png" alt="Buy Now with CoinPayments.net">
      </form>
```

I have tried this, but the problem is that it's not bringing the payment page directly and I can't customize it so that I can cancel the transaction, or run a function, its taking me to the CoinPayments website, I want a payment gateway that will bring the payment page like a popup on the page, like a JavaScript API.

I don't know of anyway that I will be able to accept bitcoin with ionic framework.

Comment: Never done this before, but have you seen this? https://github.com/bitpay/node-bitpay-client

Answer (score 0):

Using Electrum wallet could be a great free solution, also Bitpay is good solution but you need to pay 1%.

Follow the documentation: https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/merchant.html